# Json with mysql 8

Tags: mysql, json

I have a code to take a piece of my json on mysql it works perfectly on mysql 10, but on mysql 8 it doesn't work.

My code:

```
SELECT  JSON_VALUE(campos, "$.pis_nit") FROM documento;
```

I tried to do:

```
SELECT  JSON_EXTRACT(campos, "$.pis_nit") FROM documento;
```

but it shows a error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column '$.pis_nit' in 'field list'
```

Comment: There's no such thing as MySQL 10. I think you mean MariaDB 10.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. That would happen if you put backticks instead of double quotes around `$.pis_nit`.

Comment: I really got confused, sorry it's version 10 of mariaDb and the backticks shows the same error

Comment: That's my point -- you should NOT use backticks, they cause this error.

Comment: What you wrote works fine in MySQL 8.0: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9zRrCUyWM2ZV3ZPF2GsbYw/1